# I get U051 Check Ink Error on my MP 220 Canon. Can I bypass or do I need to change cartridges?

Tags: printer

I get this error:

[image]

I changed my cartridges already and I usually refill manually because I have access to free ink.

Can I bypass this error?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, also the scanner did not work. What worked for me was to turn the printer on, then click and hold the resume button (orange triangle in circle) for a few seconds. Then everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read, you have to reset the waste ink counter. I found this process and link that should help.[How to reset Cannon printers](http://tricks-collections.com/reset-printer-canon-mp140-mp160-mp180-mp210-mp220-mp460-mp470-mp500-mp510-mp530-mp600-mp610-mp800-mp820-mp810-mp830-mp960-mp970/)

Reset Waste Ink Counter Canon Pixma MP210 and Canon Pixma MP220

Start with printer off

2. Press and hold resume Button (triangle in the circle) and click “Power” button. green led should be on
3. hold the Power button, release Resume Button.
4. Without releasing the Power Button, double click “Resume” button and then release Both Buttons.
5. Click “Resume” for four times then click “Power” button, to confirm the selected action (reset counter absorber).
6. Turn off the printer and turn on again

Comment: After I do the 3rd step the printer turns off. When I realease both buttons.